# Some of my pages throw serverless function timeout

Tags: next.js, vercel

Some pages of my site built with Next and deployed on Vercel, throw serverless function timeout on production (all is working on local)

I tried to minimize the code to the maximum, to be sure the issue doesn't come from the code inside my page.

So now I'm with a page with only a useState inside, throwing an error.

There is no error in the build logs.

I'd like to give a hint that could maybe help someone understand the issue : if I rename the useState then I don't have serverless error anymore.

[image]

[image]

[image]